# "The response is not a valid JSON response." when tying to update my Meta Description

Tags: json, wordpress, meta-tags

Google is displaying the wrong meta description but when I try change it I get the:

The response is not a valid JSON response.

error.

I'm using the AIOSEO plugin and just trying to write the Description withouth using its tags which have displayed the wrong  information on google

custom writing the description in the Meta Description box

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.